# Difference between 'Foreign Key Relations' window and 'Keys' in Object explorer SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In the image, the Foreign Key Relationships window is showing the FK for the    `itemModifier_Rel` table while on the object explorer it doesn't shows the same results.

**What are the differences between these?**

I'm having a problem of duplicated keys, some DBA have a wrong process that causes this and I'm trying to fix it. 
I deleted the duplicates but now I'm seeing this. Although the resulting `CREATE TABLE` script for the table shows just 3 FK while on the Foreign Key Relationships I'm seeing 6
[image]

Here's the table's script after dropping the duplicated FK

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[itemModifier_Rel](
    [ItemModifierTypeID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ModifierItemID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ModifierSequenceID] [bigint] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemModifierTypeID] ASC,
    [ItemID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[itemModifier_Rel]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[item] ([ItemID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[itemModifier_Rel]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ItemModifierTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[itemModifierType_Cat] ([ItemModifierTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[itemModifier_Rel]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ModifierItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[item] ([ItemID])
GO
```

Comment: I ran a process to drop all the duplicated constraints, it worked but I'm still seeing some duplicates on the Foreign Key Relationships window.

Comment: Please post the table creation script. These names are auto-generated which probably means the schema contains `REFERENCES` clauses in the column definitions. Unless of course your `CREATE` script actually creates multiple foreign key constraints for the same relation. As for the difference, right click on the table and select `Refresh`

Comment: Keys are the constraint names, Foreign Key Relationships is the dialog setting the FK relationships visually. It also contains Foreign keys pointing to selected table's PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On left you see the keys constraint names under Keys. On right you have the dialog for setting up key properties visually. That dialog is listing all the foreign keys of your table plus all the foreign keys that reference to table. IOW you have 3 FK + 2 references to your table PK in that picture.

Comment: I see. I deleted some of those relations (the reference to the table) but the FK still exists. Do this compromises the DB integrity?

Comment: Hard to say :) Need to see what indexes and relationships you have. Probably it would be easier to follow creating database diagrams.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and everything seems fine. Hence the question. 
What I see is that I'll have one relation of X from Y and Y from X in that window, if I delete one of those this will not affect the FK constraint... ?